# Angular 2 rollup AoT build is bigger than normal JiT build

Tags: javascript, angular, jit, aot

I have a problem with building my app. I want to make them weight less. Im using angular 2 seed as a base. https://github.com/mgechev/angular-seed

So after im running:

```
npm run build.prod
```

my app.js is 1.5MB

after:

```
npm run build.prod.rollup.aot
```

app.js is 1.9MB

and if I run only:

```
npm run build.prod.aot
```

it is 2.2Mb.

It is totally make no sense for me. Im not able to shere my app with you cause it is a private project. I would be greatfull if someone just have an idea what can be a cause of this.

Comment: same for me, for small apps, AOT is not worth it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ahead of Time compilation has not been created to reduce code size. In some cases the compiled code is bigger, but anyway, the render time is drastically slower.

If you want to reduce the first request downloaded total size, use lazy loading modules, but I think that's not the case.

See for Lazy Loading: https://angular-2-training-book.rangle.io/handout/modules/lazy-loading-module.html

See for Server Rendering: https://github.com/robwormald/ng-universal-demo/

Comment: How can I decrease loading screen time? Is it some solutions outsite AoT?

Comment: Like I said: using lazy loading modules and server rendering. I'm gonna update the answer with tutorial link.

Comment: I have another question, so if I start using lazy loading to components, how it ll look if all app is compiled in one js file. In this case lazy loading will work?

Comment: No, It won't. Lazy loading is: Split code in several modules in order to reduce size of files that starts the application. If actually your goal is decrease first-load time, I highly recommend using server-rendering. In this case, the server render the page and send rendered html to the client while angular is loaded. The user experience is very close to classic websites.